# Unreachable Statement

Tags: apex, api

I am new to Apex and am trying to update/insert values on an account record based on the response from the REST callout. I am receiving the Unreachable statement error.

The goal is that whenever a field is updated or a new record is created the value from the field should be passed into the class with the REST callout. Then the values from the response should update certain fields on the record.

Any suggestions for best practice with implementing this type of requirement would be greatly appreciated.

The error is coming from this line:

```
String AccountVat= String.ValueOf(account.VAT__c);
```

This is the full Apex class so far.

```
public class Businessfinder {



public static List<Account> getAccounts(Id accountId) {
        List<Account> Accounts =
               [SELECT Id, Name, VAT__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId ];
            return Accounts;


String accountVat= String.ValueOf(account.VAT__c);    

 String requestEndpoint='https://data.brreg.no/enhetsregisteret/api/enheter/';
        requestEndPoint+= +accountVat;
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(requestEndPoint);
        request.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response=http.send(request);



        if(response.getStatusCode()==200){

        Map<String,Object> results=(Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());

        // Casts the values in the 'accounts' key as a list
        List<Object> accounts2 = (List<Object>) results.get('accounts2');
        System.debug('Recieved Data');
        for (Object account: accounts) {
        System.debug(account);
        account acct = new account();
        acct.Name=String.valueOf('navn');
        acct.BillingCity=String.valueOf('forretningsadresse.by');

        insert acct;
        System.debug('acct'+acct);


            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have intended to write a second method after `getAccounts()`, but missed the declaration.

```
    List<Account> Accounts =
           [SELECT Id, Name, VAT__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId ];
        return Accounts;
```

At this point, control leaves your code, making

```
String accountVat= String.ValueOf(account.VAT__c);
```

and everything else written in the body of your code unreachable - since the method's already returned, these lines will never execute.

You probably meant to add a

```
}
```

after

```
return Accounts;
```

and start a new method, but it's not totally clear from this code what your overall structure is intended to be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. I see now that missed the declaration. After doing some more research I have realized that I maybe I was on the wrong track with my initial post. I believe I may need a method to query the field from the current record. Another method for the REST callout. And then a trigger to call the class/update the record. I am new to Apex/coding in SF. Do you have any hints as to if I am on the right train of thought for implementing this solution?